# How to fire an event in AlertDialog(Xamarin.Android)?

Tags: events, xamarin.android, call

I have created the following AlertDialog:

```
Dialog dialogConfirmTransfer = new Dialog(this);
AlertDialog.Builder alertConfirmTransfer = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertConfirmTransfer.SetMessage("Confirm transfer");
alertConfirmTransfer.SetPositiveButton("Yes", delegate
{
    dialogConfirmTransfer.Cancel();
    //fire event call method MyMethod()
});


alertConfirmTransfer.SetNegativeButton("No", delegate
{
    dialogConfirmTransfer.Cancel();
});

dialogConfirmTransfer = alertConfirmTransfer.Create();
dialogConfirmTransfer.Show();

private void MyMethod()
{
    //the code I want to be executed after the event occurs
}
```

After the user has clicked `YES` I want after dialog disappearing to be fired some event which calls some method which is located in MainActivity outside the OnCreate method. There are a lot of examples on the internet but maybe because I haven't used events too often I find it difficult to apply it to my particular case. Could you provide me with the code I have to add so I can achieve what I want?

Comment: Well its very simple just show us your event code if you can

Comment: I don't have any. I want to create an event replacing `//fire event call method` and when it's line is reached a want `//call method` to be called

Comment: Hi, have you solved you problem?

Comment: Yes I will post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create custom EventHandler:

```
class FileTransferSuccessHandler
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnFileTransferSuccess;
    public void FireEvent()
    {
        if (OnFileTransferSuccess != null)
        {
            OnFileTransferSuccess(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it in code to fire the event(calling a method)

```
FileTransferSuccessHandler fileTransferSuccessHandler = new FileTransferSuccessHandler();
fileTransferSuccessHandler.OnFileTransferSuccess += ImportDataIntoDatabase;
fileTransferSuccessHandler.FireEvent();
```

And I write the code to be executed in:

```
private void ImportDataIntoDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if I'm not wrong all you want to do is fire an event on alert dialog positive selection which I guess is quite easy,

All you have to do is :

```
Dialog dialogConfirmTransfer = new Dialog(this);
AlertDialog.Builder alertConfirmTransfer = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertConfirmTransfer.SetMessage("Confirm transfer");
alertConfirmTransfer.SetPositiveButton("Yes", delegate
{
 dialogConfirmTransfer.Cancel();
 myMethod();

});


alertConfirmTransfer.SetNegativeButton("No", delegate
{
  dialogConfirmTransfer.Cancel();
 });

dialogConfirmTransfer = alertConfirmTransfer.Create();
dialogConfirmTransfer.Show();

//call method
```

Comment: But how to create it and tell it which method to be called?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with that event sir